# Verify if device is connected with internet, not only with network

Tags: android, wifi, connectivity

I need some method to verify if my network is conected to interne, and during my researchs I found some method describe below:

```
public static boolean hasInternetAccess(Context context) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) 
                (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204")
                .openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
            urlc.connect();
            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 204 &&
                        urlc.getContentLength() == 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No network available!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

...but my programs will be distributed on China, and Google is blocked on China.

I have on mind to create a method like this selecting first my localization to get a Baidoo web site - like Google on China - but make this is very expansive method to check if device is connected on some network and verify if than connected on Internet.

Comment: Send a HEAD request to any page and see if you get a response. Or try using ping.

Comment: For China probably the easiest would be something like `InetAddress.getByName("baidu.com").isReachable(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS);` and check if it throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this using `ConnectivityManager` :

```
public static boolean  isConnectedToInternet(Context context){
        boolean isConnected= false;
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connectivityManager .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);        
        isConnected= (wifi.isAvailable() && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting() || (mobile.isAvailable() && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()));
        return isConnected;
    }
```

You can also check the selected answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089668/detecting-network-connectivity-on-android?rq=1)

Comment: ishmaelMakitla  its not answer He expected please read question

Comment: Maheshwar Ligade, I checked - I thought he said "sending HTTP request" is expensive and wanted a way of checking if there's Internet/data connectivity. I see in your suggested answer you are sending a HTTP-GET to Yahoo - whereas in my case I am using connectivity manager to check if the device itself is connected to Internet without making a request. Did I perhaps miss something? Thanks for the comment.

Comment: " Verify if device is connected with internet," He want this one not network connected or not which is given by your code

Comment: This code only verify if Wifi is enable or disable, and not if exists some internet connection. I use a similar to verify my wifi enable or disable.

Answer (score 0):

[China does](https://www.techinasia.com/8-android-app-stores-china) have sites to host android apps. China has [proxy servers](http://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-cn/) you could use to see what is blocked and could be used to thwart whatever firewall China has. I strongly encourage you to consider legal ramifications. TCP/IP utilities or even a browser can be used to test a connection. I am not sure I fully understand your question. You have Android apps that will be used in devices located in China and a server located somewhere you want to test a connection. China has [web hosting](http://www.hostsearch.com/hostdirectory/china-web-hosting.asp) if you want to go that route. Do you need access to Google API's?

Comment: No, I don't need access Google API's yet, but I have more of one servers, and a service redirecting to more faster server. One of this servers is localized on China, but Chineze server is not a better and sometimes his is broken. When this happening the software try conneting others servers but, just because proxy and firewalls, the redirecting flow slowly and timeout problems occured frequently!